# Don't suggest a tag that I've added a synonym of

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-tags

I have already added the tag [comment](/questions/tagged/comment), but it is also suggesting I add the tag [comments](/questions/tagged/comments):

[image]

Could it grey it out, or hide it, if I have already added a synonym please?

Also, can there be a space between suggested tags: and the tag, like this:

> suggested tags: [comment](/questions/tagged/comment)

not what it is now:

> suggested tags:[comment](/questions/tagged/comment)